# Move only the first file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm trying to build a script that moves the first file (ordered by name) if the folder contains more than 100 files in it.

I could only get here but it moves all the files.

Can someone help me please?

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d C:\SOURCE ^|find /c /v ""') do set "remaining=%%a" 

forfiles /P C:\SOURCE /M * /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if %remaining% geq 100 
  move @FILE "C:\TARGET""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Echo Off
For /F %%a In ('dir /b ^| sort') do set "first_file=%~fa" & goto break
:break
move "%first_file%" "C:\Target"
```